# ¿Cómo se habla como un pirata en español?

Tags: traducción, modismos, expresiones, vocabulario-técnico

En inglés un pirata dice *"Ahoy, matey!"*. ¿Cómo se dice *"Ahoy, matey!"* en español? ¿Hay otras frases comunes de piratas?

Comment: Los piratas eran Ingleses en su mayoría. Los piratas de origen español eran pocos y poco conocidos. El pirata "traducido" más común en la actualidad es el Capitán McCallister de los Simpson y su expresión más conocida es ARRR. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lWjV0c3u8A  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-ZYDiXME4k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La palabra [*ahoy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahoy_(greeting)) es una interjección usada en inglés para llamar la atención de un barco o nave, la cual a su vez viene de [*hoy*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoy), que servía tanto como interjección como para denominar ciertos tipos de barcos.
Si lo que buscamos es **la expresión equivalente en español, sería «¡Ah!» o, más específicamente, «¡Ah del barco!»**.

El uso de ***ah*** como [vocativo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_vocativo) (para llamar la atención de alguien) era [común en distintos ámbitos](http://rinconaufrago.blogspot.com/2010/07/las-palabras-y-su-vida.html), y de hecho el DLE sigue recogiendo la expresión [«ah de la casa»](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7lsKMtR#AhxyBek).
En cuanto al uso de «¡Ah del barco!», se puede encontrar en libros del s. XIX (cuando el [Romanticismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticismo) hizo populares en España las novelas de aventuras) como [este](https://books.google.es/books?id=IntX1E0SMx8C&dq=%22ah%20del%20barco%22&hl=es&pg=PA216#v=onepage&q=%22ah%20del%20barco%22&f=false), [este](https://books.google.es/books?id=1YQvAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22ah%20del%20barco%22&hl=es&pg=PA492#v=onepage&q=%22ah%20del%20barco%22&f=false) y [este](https://books.google.es/books?id=tYcUAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22ah%20del%20barco%22&hl=es&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q=%22ah%20del%20barco%22&f=false), aunque el ejemplo más claro de todos es la [traducción de 1880 de *The Phantom Ship, or The Flying Dutchman*](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&tbs=sbd%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1899&tbm=bks&q=%22ah%20del%20barco%22%20%22buque%20fantasma%22), que dice:

> —¡**Ah del barco**! dijo Krantz, encaramado sobre la borda, y agitando el sombrero.—Todo inútil; la fragata avanzaba, veiase la espuma saltar bajo su estamenara, y pronto estuvo á un tiro de pistola.
>   —¡**Ah del barco**! gritaron los marmeros [...]

Donde el [original inglés](https://books.google.es/books?id=ppErAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA146&ots=SoGUw2GmKr&dq=ahoy%20said%20Krantz&hl=es&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q=ahoy%20said%20Krantz&f=false) dice, precisamente:

> "**Ship, ahoy**!" cried Krantz on the gunwale, waving his hat. It was useless—down she came with the waters foaming under her bows and was now within pistol shot of the Utrecht.
>   "**Ship, ahoy**!" roared all the sailors [...]

Por tanto, como digo: si lo que buscas es el término en español equivalente al *ahoy* inglés, sería "ah del barco".

---

No obstante, si lo que quieres saber es cuál es la fórmula usada como saludo entre los hispanohablantes practicantes del [pastafarismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastafarismo), entonces lo adecuado no es usar el equivalente español de la expresión inglesa original, sino la que sea que haya establecido la Iglesia Pastafari. En tal caso, como bien indica [mdewey en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28340/13628), la expresión sería "¡Ahoy, amigo!" (pronunciada aspirando la H, como en inglés, entiendo).

Answer (score 4):

According to the Wikipedia entry on September 19 which is [Día internacional de hablar como un pirata](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADa_Internacional_de_Hablar_como_un_Pirata) you are supposed to say:

> ¡Ahoy, amigo!

Comment: Da la impresión de que la página que enlazas es una traducción de la versión inglesa, incluyendo esa expresión.

Comment: It seems that the linked page is just a translation from the original English version, including that expression.

Comment: The expressions used by pirates are in english, as most part of them were native english speakers. That's why there are no common pirate expressions in spanish, but just from the other side, like ¡Que vienen los piratas! ;)

Comment: @RubioRic in fact it misses out the part which gives the most characteristic pirate sound (to me anyway (Arrh). If I wanted to sound like a pirate I would say "Arrh, Jim lad". Jim would be Jim Hawkins the cabin boy. That I thought was truly untranslatable which is why I left it out.

Comment: @mdewey According to the Urban Dictionary: "Arr: Most often used by pirates, this is a word that can essentially mean anything. Usually a response in the affirmative, or general exclamation." You're right, I don't know any Spanish word that "can mean anything" XD